# Clicking almost 2 identical urls with imacro

Tags: imacros

I am working on a imacro script and i am just stuck with it and can't figure out what i am doing wrong.
It is a macro thát visits a certain forum part and it needs to click 2 links.
They are almost identical except for 1 part.
It is used to download attachments.

Code i got at the moment:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:aid* EXTRACT=href
tab open
tab t=2
url goto={{!EXTRACT}}

TAB CLOSE

TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:aid* EXTRACT=href
tab open
tab t=2
url goto={{!EXTRACT}}
```

I also tried it like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*linkhere*/forum.php?mod=attachment&aid=*                 EXTRACT=href
tab open
tab t=2
url goto={{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAB CLOSE

TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*.pdf EXTRACT=HREF
SET link EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/(http.*)\./)[1];")
URL GOTO={{link}}
```

but still no luck.
As you see 1 file is a image, but the 2nd file can be a pdf or zip/rar file.
Most of them are pdf tough.

Hopefully can point me in the right direction with this as i got no clue anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply save the files directly?

Do you need to open them in a different tab?

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:http://*.jpg CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM`

```
TAG XPATH="/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/h2/span[2]/a[1]" CONTENT=EVENT:SAVETARGETAS
```

or something like that depending on what you have there.

I prefer to refer items by XPATH, but that's just me